# How to click on a button which doesn't have a clickable:true state in Appium+Java?

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm writing tests for an app to which I don't have access to the source code, nor has anyone close to me. At a certain point, I insert login/password info and the Log In button becomes green and I can tap on it. However, I'm not being able to automate that action, because even though I can tap on the button on the screen, its 'clickable' property remains false, as do all the other properties besides the 'enabled', which is always true, even when the button isn't available to be tapped. 
[Screenshot of the node details on UIAutomatorViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mH85.png)

The only thing I can think of is to click on it when it becomes green, but I have no idea on how I could implement that, and I don't think this is a very elegant solution.
Any help is appreciated, I can't get to the other tests until I get this part done.

I'm using UI Automator Viewer to see the different states of the button, and WebDriverWait/ExpectedConditions to wait for the button to be available. Even though it never enables the 'clickable' property, I've tried using elementToBeClickable and visibilityOfElementLocated, unsuccessfully.

This is where I'm at right now.

```java
public void waitAndClick(String local) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(local)));
        getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(local)).click();
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element location and then tap by coordinates:

```
List<MobileElement> element = (MobileElement) getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(local));
Point location = element.getLocation();
ITouchAction action = new TouchAction(getDriver());
action.tap(location.x, location.y).perform();
```